# When setting a session with PHP, how do you make it global to the entire site?

Tags: php, session, persistence

I am creating a session and I want a variable to be available for the entire site, so for example:

Joe Soap lands on a page called *red-widgets.php*, - Joe's session variable is let's say 'red-widgets'. Joe then clicks on another page called *blue-widgets.php*. I would like the session variable to be still the original 'red-widgets'.

How can this be done with the url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not limited to one session variable, you can have as many as you need.

```
session_start();

if ( !isset($_SESSION['widget']) ) {
  $_SESSION['widget'] = 'i am changed only if there isnt already a widget session var';
}

$_SESSION['someOtherVar'] = 'i am being changed on every page';
```

Comment: Sorry guys, complete rookie question. Just tested there and it works as planned. So basically session variables are global?, but where do they 'stay'?

Comment: On the server. If you haven't changed anything the php-files handler saves the session data to files in the directory specified by session.save_path, see http://docs.php.net/session.configuration#ini.session.save-path

Comment: Ah gotcha. Thanks ... again VolkerK

Answer (score 4):

Whenever a PHP page loads, just call `session_start();`.  This will either 1. start a new session if one doesn't exist, or 2. restart whatever session was previously established.  To make a new session variable, do this:

```
session_start(); // start or restart the session
$_SESSION['mySessionVariableName'] = "My session variable value.";
```

If you want to kill a session so that you can start a new one, you can do:

```
session_destroy();
```

If you want to erase all session variables but not kill the current session, you can do:

```
session_unset();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:
on red-widgets.php:

```
 session_start(); 
 $_SESSION['red-widgets'] = 1;
```

on blue-widgets.php:

```
session_start();
 if(!$_SESSION['red-widgets']){
  //Joe weren't on red-widget.php, diffrent action here...
}
```